# start notification progress bar from one activity and end from broadcast receiver

Tags: android, notifications, progress-bar, message, builder

Can I start notification with progress bar from one activity and end it from broadcast receiver when the receiver finishes receiving all messages sent status. I am trying to send number of messages and I want to launch the notification with progress bar like in downloading situation when the send button is clicked and I want it to be there until the broadcast receiver finish checking sent status for all of them. Can it be done please I need some help.

I tried starting the notification from the receiver for first message sent and tried to end with the last one but I got stupid here as the receiver class creates object for each messages individually so when I want to end it at last message I get NullPointerException as the builder is not intialized for this last message. Can it be done in other ways.

Comment: What you did before?

Comment: I had previously started the notification from the broadcast receiver but that leads to wait for a time until broadcast receiver starts to recieve and that is a bit long time.

Comment: What specific problems are you having? Just update the same `Notification` appropriately in the `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: Mike the only problem I am having is the broadcast receiver doesn't act right after message sending button is pressed in main UI thread and that leads to late or should I say very late notification (with progress bar) to appear at notification bar. And all I want is I want to work with the same notification from both the activity and broadcast receiver and please I need to know is it possible or done earlier and how.